# Why intent makes my application crashed?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-listview

I just want to ask you why using intent makes my system crashed? I've used same codes before and it works, then when I use it again now it won't. What do you think the problem guys?

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void okay(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

## 2nd Activity (If I clicked the main activity, I just want this activity pop)

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] grocery_categories = {"Beverages", "Bakery", "Canned Goods", "Condiments", "Dairy", "Snacks", "Frozen Foods",
                                "Meat", "Produce", "Cleaners", "Paper Goods", "Personal Care", "Others"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, grocery_categories);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String grocery = (String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(listView.getContext(),Login.class);
            listView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            //or create other intents here
        }
    });

}
```

XML of MainActivity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/rl_main_activity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_grocery_bckgrnd"
    android:src="@drawable/mobile_grocery"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MOBILE GROCERY"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_grocery_app"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Application"
    android:id="@+id/application"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mobile_grocery_app"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/application"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/application"
    android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/username"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:password="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/application"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/application"
    android:onClick="okay" />
```

XML of Login Activity (2nd Activity)

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/login_bckgrnd"
    android:src="@drawable/login_bckgrnd"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



</ListView>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.mobilegroceryapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat

```
  .085    2019-2087/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
09-29 01:54:28.085    2019-2087/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
09-29 01:54:28.085    2019-2087/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
09-29 01:54:28.085    2019-2087/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
09-29 01:54:28.085    2019-2087/? I/InputDispatcher﹕ Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
09-29 01:54:28.190    2019-2088/? I/InputReader﹕ Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=]
09-29 01:54:28.285  30351-30351/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.graphics.Bitmap.getAllocationByteCount, referenced from method com.facebook.imagepipeline.a.d.a.a
09-29 01:54:28.285  30351-30351/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 625: Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;.getAllocationByteCount ()I
09-29 01:54:28.285  30351-30351/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
09-29 01:54:28.355  30482-30482/? D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
09-29 01:54:28.355    2019-2074/? D/BatteryService﹕ update start
09-29 01:54:28.360    2019-2079/? D/KeyguardViewMediator﹕ setHidden false
09-29 01:54:28.360    1732-1732/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ id=13169 Removed TcreenSaver idx=4 MapSz=10
```

Hope some pro help me to my problem. Somebody says It's simple but I can't resolved sir.

Comment: Could you update your post with a stacktrace?

Comment: What is stacktrace sir? I'm beginner. You mean logcat?

Comment: @Lawrence: `Why intent makes my application crashed?` which intent?

Comment: Yes, in your logcat whenever there is an exception that isn't caught or an exception that is logged it will tell you what the error is, where it occurred and sometimes proposed suggestions on fixing it. Try searching your logcat for "FATAL EXCEPTION"

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Look at my MainActivity sir! I tried to intent the Login Class but it crashed. By the way sir! I'm trying to develop a Mobile Grocery App for my thesis

Comment: @Lawrence: Added `Login` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: You're not providing enough information for us to help you, so at this point everything is just an educated guess.

Comment: @nbokmans Sir excuse me! When I see my logcat there are so many lines. I mean stanzas. Which of them show the error? My sincere apologize

Comment: @jyanks Sorry sir for being trash. I'm trying to figure out what they're saying cuz I'm beginner. Bear with me sir

Comment: Can you check to see if the Login activity is in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? Your code to launch the activity looks fine.

Comment: Lawrence, can you please put the Logcat from the error section(you have 5 types of section, "verbose","info","debug","error" etc..., change to error section and please attach that logcat here

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Login Activity to your `AndroidManifest.xml` so that the android operating system can find the Activity that the intent is referencing.

```
<activity
android:name=".Activities.Login"
android:label="Login" />
```

Comment: how is android:name=".Activities.Login" going to help ? there is no such ".Activities.Login" activity, just Login activity

Comment: @Lawrence hasn't included enough information (like the package name) to be able to supply a 100% accurate answer. The `.Activities.Login` is the best guess at what the activity class' name is (if it's stored in a subpackage from the main java folder named `Activities`). It is most likely something like `com.lawrence.activities.Login`, but again, it's impossible to say without seeing the actual package name.

Comment: Also, using the `.<ACTIVITY NAME>` syntax shortcuts the long name for the package.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to show us your stacktrace for any useful feedback. I suspect you aren't declaring the Login activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` correctly.

LogCat will contain the error stacktrace. Most likely you will see a giant block of red text that will indicate the part we are interested in. Below is an example of one of my stacktraces. Hopefully it helps you find it.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package.name.ThingDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long com.package.api.model.Thing.getId()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)`