# Intent Crashing. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-layout, date

I just want to ask you why using intent makes my app crash? I've used same codes before and it works, now when I used it again it aint. What do you think the problem of this code. I didnt find anything.

## MainActivity JAVA

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void okay(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

## Login JAVA (I just want this activity pop if i call its id)

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] grocery_categories = {"Beverages", "Bakery", "Canned Goods", "Condiments", "Dairy", "Snacks", "Frozen Foods",
                                "Meat", "Produce", "Cleaners", "Paper Goods", "Personal Care", "Others"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, grocery_categories);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String grocery = (String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(listView.getContext(),Login.class);
            listView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            //or create other intents here
        }
    });

}
```

## MainActivity.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/rl_main_activity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_grocery_bckgrnd"
    android:src="@drawable/mobile_grocery"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MOBILE GROCERY"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_grocery_app"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Application"
    android:id="@+id/application"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mobile_grocery_app"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/application"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/application"
    android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/username"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:password="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/application"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/application"
    android:onClick="okay" />
```

## Login.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.admin.mobilegroceryapp.Login"
android:id="@+id/rl_login">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/login_bckgrnd"
    android:src="@drawable/login_bckgrnd"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



</ListView>
```

## Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.mobilegroceryapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## LOGCAT

```html
9-29 02:17:52.595    2019-2074/? D/BatteryService﹕ level:34 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true voltage: 3918 temperature: 350 technology: Li-ion  

AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17303267 invalid charger:0 online:1 charge type:0 current avg:1
09-29 02:17:52.610    2140-2140/? D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController﹕ onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
09-29 02:17:52.610    2140-2140/? D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController﹕ onReceive() - level:34
09-29 02:17:52.610    2140-2140/? D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController﹕ onReceive() - plugged:2
09-29 02:17:52.615    2140-2140/? D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController﹕ onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
09-29 02:17:52.625    2019-2074/? D/BatteryService﹕ turn on LED for charging
09-29 02:17:52.635    2140-2140/? D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar﹕ ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
09-29 02:17:52.650    2140-2140/? D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar﹕ NORMAL_BATTERY
09-29 02:17:52.670    1381-1381/? E/MtpService﹕ In MTPAPP onReceive:android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
09-29 02:17:52.670    1381-1381/? E/MtpService﹕ battPlugged Type : 2
09-29 02:17:53.405    2019-2078/? V/AlarmManager﹕ waitForAlarm result :2
09-29 02:17:53.540    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_updateAllWidgets false
09-29 02:17:53.540    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_buildWidgetView enabled=false
09-29 02:17:53.555    2019-2031/? W/AlarmManager﹕ FACTORY_ON= 0
09-29 02:17:56.555    2019-2078/? V/AlarmManager﹕ waitForAlarm result :2
09-29 02:17:56.690    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_updateAllWidgets false
09-29 02:17:56.690    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_buildWidgetView enabled=false
09-29 02:17:56.695    2019-5434/? W/AlarmManager﹕ FACTORY_ON= 0
09-29 02:17:59.690    2019-2078/? V/AlarmManager﹕ waitForAlarm result :2
09-29 02:17:59.800    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_updateAllWidgets false
09-29 02:17:59.800    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_buildWidgetView enabled=false
09-29 02:17:59.805    2019-2019/? W/AlarmManager﹕ FACTORY_ON= 0
09-29 02:18:00.000    2019-2078/? V/AlarmManager﹕ waitForAlarm result :8
09-29 02:18:00.010    2019-2062/? V/AlarmManager﹕ ClockReceiver onReceive() ACTION_TIME_TICK
09-29 02:18:00.010    2019-2062/? W/AlarmManager﹕ FACTORY_ON= 0
09-29 02:18:00.055    2140-2140/? D/STATUSBAR-Clock﹕ onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
09-29 02:18:00.080    2140-2140/? D/STATUSBAR-Clock﹕ onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
09-29 02:18:00.100    2140-2140/? D/TextLayoutCache﹕ Cache value 0x5ea48dc0 deleted, size = 144
09-29 02:18:00.160  30579-30579/? D/Launcher﹕ onTrimMemory. Level: 80
09-29 02:18:00.160  30579-30579/? D/Launcher﹕ releaseShadows called
09-29 02:18:00.165  30579-30579/? W/ManagedEGLContext﹕ doTerminate failed: EGL count is 2 but managed count is 1
09-29 02:18:02.810    2019-2078/? V/AlarmManager﹕ waitForAlarm result :2
09-29 02:18:02.940    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_updateAllWidgets false
09-29 02:18:02.945    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_buildWidgetView enabled=false
09-29 02:18:02.955    2019-2031/? W/AlarmManager﹕ FACTORY_ON= 0
09-29 02:18:05.960    2019-2078/? V/AlarmManager﹕ waitForAlarm result :2
09-29 02:18:06.090    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_updateAllWidgets false
09-29 02:18:06.090    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_buildWidgetView enabled=false
09-29 02:18:06.095    2019-5434/? W/AlarmManager﹕ FACTORY_ON= 0
09-29 02:18:07.135    2019-2210/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 6737
09-29 02:18:09.095    2019-2078/? V/AlarmManager﹕ waitForAlarm result :2
09-29 02:18:09.200    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_updateAllWidgets false
09-29 02:18:09.200    5709-5709/? D/InCarWidget:main﹕ VLG_buildWidgetView enabled=false
09-29 02:18:09.205    2019-2019/? W/AlarmManager﹕ FACTORY_ON= 0
```

Hope somebody can help me

Comment: provide your complete both xml files for MainActivity and Login, as its missing closing tag of RelativeLayout in both the xml. and try to put all the codes including imports and package name aswell

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why intent makes my application crashed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828354/why-intent-makes-my-application-crashed)

Comment: Please provide an useful log which shows the exception stack trace. The log you're currently showing doesn't give us any information about your app's process.

Answer (score 0):

Your provided Logcat is not useful to find the exact error. But, change your `okay` method to this.

```
    public void okay(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

`this` refers to `onClick`, So, change to `MainActivity.this`.

And why you want to start the same activity again on onClick?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String grocery = (String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(listView.getContext(),Login.class);
            listView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: What you want to achieve? where app throws error? Kindly post with correct log to provide you the solution.

Comment: I just want to pop the login.activity to  view my the list view I've been created using the button in main activity (OK button).

Comment: Provide the valid logcat.